# Create a Subject

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rxjs

I've seen this in RxJS, but i haven't found the equivalent in RxJava. Does anyone have any idea how to set something up like this in java?

[RxJS Subject.create(observer, observable)](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md#rxsubjectcreateobserver-observable)

> Creates a subject from the specified observer and observable.
>
> **Arguments**
>
> observer (Observer): The observer used to send messages to the subject.
>
> observable (Observable): The observable used to subscribe to messages sent from the subject.

Basically this would be a subject through which you could send data to another observer, and have an observable which would send data back to the subjects subscriber.

I'm trying to replicate the code seen at [this github issue post](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/112#issuecomment-65328250) in RxJava.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RxJava I think the closest you can get is to subscribe to the Observable passing the Subject as the Observer.

```
final Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
final AsyncSubject<Integer> subject = AsyncSubject.create();
observable.subscribe(subject);
subject.subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Integer integer) {
        // TODO
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Subjects can be created in RxJava as well. You can create them through the factory methods of each type. So for example if you want to create an AsyncSubject you can use:

```
Subject<String> subject = AsyncSubject.<String>create();
```

Refer to this documentation for the different type of subjects that are supported: Subject subject = AsyncSubject.create(); If you want to return it to the user you can of course downcast it to Observable so the user has no clue it is actually a Subject.

Referencing your linked issue, you can use the on* methods on the subject to feed data into it, and the Observer then can just consume it.

Comment: Thanks moidaschl for your reply. I know how to create subject, i'm just wondering of the setup in the above mentioned github issue post is possible to do. (ie have a subject to which you feed data, which is fed to another obseravable, and have an observable that has the subject as a subscriber)